# Loss of array elements after putting .innerHTML = ""

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

In my HTML I have a content div that contains articles created by a php script and handled with JQuery and Javascript. With Javascript I collect those articles into an array with the 'getElementsByClassName' function. 
The scripts and HTML I'm writing here are simplified. I need this array because I'm trying to make that if the length of the array is larger than 10, only 10 articles are displayed per page. So page 1 will be index 0 to 9 of the array, page 2 index 10 to 19, etc.
Now,

Take this html code.

```
<body>
<div id="content">
  <div class="article">
    <p>Article 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <p>Article 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <p>Article 3</p>
  </div>
</content>
</body>
```

And this Javascript code.

```
$.post("getarticles.php",{ page:"home" } ,function(data){
        //place the content
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = jQuery.trim(data);

        //put elements in array
        arrArticles = document.getElementsByClassName("article");
        alert(arrArticles.length);

        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";
        alert(arrArticles.length);
})
```

The first alert gives me "3", which is correct.. But the second alert gives me "0". Why is the array losing it's elements after the elements have been put in it?

By the way, the 'data' variable is a string of HTML passed on by a php script.
For example: In the php script I have the code

```
echo "<div class="article"><p>Article 1</p></div><div class="article"><p>Article 2</p></div><div class="article"><p>Article 3</p></div>"
```

&

```
document.getElementById("contentWrap").innerHTML = "";
```

I know this is causing the problem, but I don't know why. Can anyone explain or provide an alternative?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What element has the id `contentWrap`?

Comment: BTW: You've already got jQuery, so use $('#article') instead of document.getElementById.

Comment: If you are going to empty the content after, they why insert it to begin with? Just to `$(data).find('.article').length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like document.getElementByClassName is returning a reference to the element array which is being updated when you change the mark up. Not sure why; perhaps somebody better informed than me can answer that.

Using jQuery to select the array worked for me:

```
var arrArticles = $(".article")
```

Answer (score 10):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a dynamic array (actually a live `NodeList`) that will change dynamically if/when you modify the DOM.  So, if you change the content with innerHTML and elements in that array are affected, the array will change automatically.

If you want to keep this list of elements and make it not be live (so it won't change when the DOM is changed), you can make a copy of the NodeList into a normal array (that is not dynamic) and once it is in a normal array, the references to the DOM elements will keep them from getting destroyed.  It won't prevent them from getting changed if your code changes their contents, but it will keep them around even if your code caused them to get removed from the DOM.

One way to make a copy of the dynamic `NodeList` into a static array is like this:

```
// fetch dynamic NodeList
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("article");
// make static copy of NodeList into normal array
items = Array.prototype.slice.call(items);
```

Or, since your post is tagged with jQuery, you can just use jQuery in the first place which contains a static array of nodes that isn't affected by other changes in the DOM:

```
var items = $(".article");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand what you say, but not your solution (not experienced enough). Used Alan his solution, very simple that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("article");
```

return [NodeList array], this array contain pointers to DOM elements

```
arrArticles = anotherArray;
```

this code do not create a copy of anotherArray, but it is make a pointer to values form anotherArray.

So when elements in anotherArray will be deleted, in arrArticles elements will dissapear also.